# Interpreting output of .show capacity command

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to make sense of output return `.show capacity` command. I am finding that different clusters I have access to have the same capacity policy, yet when I run `.show capacity` command I see different number in 'Total' column of the resultset. Isn't total determined from capacity policy?

Also, what it means when we say for example remaining capacity for 'DataExport' resource is say 30 ? Does it mean that 30 more export commands can be accommodated (all with their unique OperationsId) without getting queued up (if it queues up at all when more export commands are issued than 'Remaining' slots) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the `scope` property, the output of `.show capacity` may depend not only on the cluster's capacity policy, but also on the cluster's workload groups and their request rate limit policies.

- Even if unaltered, both the former and the latter would be different by default in clusters that have different SKUs (different number of cores per node), or a different number of nodes (total number of cores).

`30` means that up to 30 export commands may run concurrently. the 31st will be throttled.

- It doesn't necessarily mean the cluster can't physically handle more than 30, rather it's a (configurable) threshold at which requests of this type will be throttled, to limit the export workload from consuming too many resources.
- There's no queuing of such requests (unless your workload group definition and its request queueing policy specify that queuing is enabled for these kinds of requests)

Comment: we are having the same SKU for these clusters and also no workload defined -- the only thing that varies is number of worker nodes making total number of cores per cluster vary -- so probably that's causing this difference

Comment: Also -- if I check my capacity policy object for the cluster , I see that under 'ExportCapacity' bag the values are:- ClusterMaximumConcurrentOperations is 100 and CoreUtilizationCoefficient is 0.25 -- but if I check output of .show capacity command , actual Total for 'DataExport' resource is only 12. What do I need to do to increase this actual from 12 to say 100 ? The only command I am aware of is for changing capacity policy object but that is already 100 , I rather want actual 'Total' for 'DataExport' to be shown as 100 (which is merely 12 as of now).

Comment: the formula (as appears in the docs) is: `Minimum(ClusterMaximumConcurrentOperations, Number of nodes in cluster * Maximum(1, Core count per node * CoreUtilizationCoefficient))`. if you emplace the variables from your comment, you get: `Minimum(100, Number of nodes in cluster * Core count per node * 0.25)`. which means - in order to reach higher capacity, you could: (1) scale out; (2) scale up (unless you're already running with a SKU that has 16 cores per node); (3) change the coefficient (_highly discouraged_)